# Change EditText line colour and EditText cursor colour programatically for minimum API level 14?

Tags: android

I had try below snippet but its not working for below API 21:

```
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(editTextColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(editTextColor,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

So please suggest me how can I Change for API 14.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
Drawable drawable = editText.getBackground();
drawable.setColorFilter(editTextColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
    editText.setBackground(drawable);
}else{
    editText.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, please accept question @Ronitkadwane

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to ***@null*** should result in the use of **android:textColor** as the cursor color.

Attribute `textCursorDrawable` is available in API level 12 and higher.

Comment: this is from xml not programatically